# ld: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found (normally in libSystem.dylib)

Tags: macos, fortran, homebrew, gfortran

Fortran compiler does not work and I think it's kind of PATH problem.

I'm using MacOS Mojave 10.14.5. I was trying to run a fortran code I got from someone else. It compiled fine but when running it I got error. First it was segmentation fault so I was not sure what is wrong. But I'm 90% sure the code is not wrong because it have been run by other person. But compiling and running simple code like HelloWorld ran fine.

I found that my gfortran is using anaconda version (4.8.5?), so I changed it to Homebrew version (9.1.0) editing bashrc file. After that (I'm not sure what exactly changed the problem. I was trying many things I can find on Google, like reinstalling gcc. I may have messed up paths)
my fortran compiler failed to compile even the HelloWorld code.

```
PRINT *, "Hello World!"
END
```

.

```
(base) dyn-137-229-27-249:~ jjung11$ gfortran hello.f90 -o hello
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd
ld: symbol dyld_stub_binder not found (normally in libSystem.dylib).  Needed to perform lazy binding to function __gfortran_set_args for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It says I need to do lazy binding but I have no idea what it means and even though I googled for it I couldn't learn how to do it.

Also the error I've seen lots of times trying to run my own code is following:

```
(base) dyn-137-229-27-249:~ jjung11$ /Volumes/easystore/code/mhdread_sc ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: /sasbuild/local/xmac01/GNU_CC_CXX_7.1/gcc_7.1.0/lib/libgfortran.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/easystore/code/mhdread_sc
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I was trying to change dyld path but not successfully. In fact I have not a good idea about what it means.

The error I get for the my own code currently is following:

```
/Volumes/easystore/code/mhdread_sc -grid ../openggcm_run/2008Jun28_002/2008Jun28_002.grid -fin ../openggcm_run/2008Jun28_002/target/2008Jun28_002.3df. -diptime 2008:06:28:10:00:0.000 -fth 2008Jun28_002.TB_GSEorbit.mhd -fsc TB.GSE.orbit -t0 3600 -tt 43200 -dt 60
 test
 3600                                                                                                                                                                                                    
At line 55 of file mhdread_sc.f
Internal Error: get_unit(): Bad internal unit KIND
```

Actually even though I was struggling with this problem for days I'm just a beginner in programming (Brew/Xcode/PATH/bashrc/mac) so please be kind for the solution. I may not understand it if it's difficult.

Edit-
new error

```
(base) dyn-137-229-27-249:~ jjung11$ which gfortran -a
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
(base) dyn-137-229-27-249:~ jjung11$ gfortran -o hello.f90 hello
ld: can't link with a main executable file 'hello' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: for diagnosis, please give the result of `which -a gfortran`

Comment: @PierredeBuyl (base) $ which -a gfortran
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
/Users/jjung11/anaconda3/bin/gfortran
/usr/local/bin/gfortran

Comment: There are two installs, I suggest that you remove the `/usr/local/bin/gfortran` if you plan to use only the conda version. How did you install? (self-compilation, binary installer, etc)? Is your computer managed or are you the admin?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I'm not an admin but I can use sudo. anaconda one was automatically installed when I installed anaconda for Python3. And I used brew install gcc to install /usr/local/bin/gfortran (I think.) One problem is version of anaconda one is low (4.8.5) and I don't know how to update it.

Comment: Can you remove the anaconda setting from `~/.bashrc`, restart the terminal, and try again? You might need to log out and in again (I don't know at what point mac os reinitializes the shell environment).

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I edited PATH in bashrc and now compiling gfortran generates another error. I edited my post to show new error.

Comment: Now, I can only think of very generic advice: make sure that the "developer tools" provided by Apple are up-to-date, update homebrew, update the gcc/gfortran install from homebrew. If that does not work I can't think of ways to diagnose and/or fix the install remotely.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl I reinstalled Apple developer tool (Xcode) and removed anaconda setting from bashrc. Now I can compile HelloWorld! Thanks. However, my own code makes a segmentation fault, but now I think it's the code problem. Though it ran fine on the PC of the person who gave the code to me, these things can happen... right?

Comment: Hi, the segmentation fault is another issue. Look up "fortran segmentation fault" on stackoverflow first and if you cannot find the answer open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like there are conflicting version of the compilers and/or of the runtime libraries.

Remove the anaconda setting from `~/.bashrc`.

Then, make sure that the "developer tools" provided by Apple are up-to-date, update homebrew, update the gcc/gfortran install from homebrew. If that does not work I can't think of ways to diagnose and/or fix the install remotely.

Comment: Interesting that you suggested removing anaconda setting. I had a similar problem when compiling a Golang project. Turns out the problem was that I had changed my conda environment. When I went back to the base conda environment everything was fixed. Thanks for your explanation, it helped me solve my issue.